# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "XXX" at path "_id" for model "Product"

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
 enter code here
const express=require('express');

const router= express.Router();

const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler');


const Product=require('../models/productModel');

router.get('/', asyncHandler(async (req,res)=>{
    const products=await Product.find({})
    res.send(products)
}));

router.get('/:id',asyncHandler(async(req,res)=>{
    const product=await Product.findById(req.params.id)
    
    if(product){
        res.json(product)
    }else{
        res.status(404).json({message:"product not found"})
    }`enter code here`
}));


    enter code here

module.exports=router`enter code here`
```

here i get data of products and product with id in postman or browser but if i enter wrong id it shows castError and in console log it shows it is internal server 500 error

Comment: If you enter a wrong `_id` you get an error saying the `_id` is wrong... what did you expected?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain the error more extensively in case someone else happens to understand why.

`_id`'s into Mongo are created in a specific way. You can check the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) where is explained the `_id` is an object called `ObjectId` and is compound by:

- A 4-byte timestamp value, representing the ObjectId’s creation, measured in seconds since the Unix epoch
- A 5-byte random value
- A 3-byte incrementing counter, initialized to a random value

That implies that not just any value will be accepted.

When you do a query matching the `_id`, mongo expect an `ObjectId`(or at least, come type that could be parsed as `string`).

So if you try to use a bad `_id`, (for example `-1` or `XXX`), the error will be thrown. Mongo can't parse `-1` to `ObjectId`

If you are testing your application and you want to use a fake `_id` you need to generate a valid one.

Using `mongoose` you can call use this function: `mongoose.Types.ObjectId()`.

The value return is a new `_id` generated, so it has a valid format.

Comment: but if i enter wrong id it should show 404 error as it is not found . but casting error with 500 internal server error.

Comment: No, if the `_id` cannot be parsed it wil throw an error, not will do the qery and return an empty document. You can add a `try/catch` statement to ensure return `400` when the query fails.