# mongoose Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

please I don't understand why I have this problem :

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5fa41e7f4ee57a30687e80e9 " at path "_id" for model "page"
Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters,
```

After this code

```
router.post('/edit-page/:slog', (req, res) => {

    req.checkBody('title', 'Le champs titre doit être remplis').notEmpty()
    req.checkBody('content', 'Le champs content doit être remplis').notEmpty();
    let title = req.body.title
    let slog = req.body.slog.replace(/\x+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    if (slog == "") slog = title.replace(/\x+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    let content = req.body.content
    let id = req.body.id

    const errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
        res.render('admin/edit_page', {
            errors: errors,
            title: title,
            slog: slog,
            content: content,
            id: id
        })
    } else {
        Page.findOne({ slog: slog, _id: { "$ne": id } }, (err, page) => {
            if (page) {
                req.flash('danger', 'Cette page existe, choisis une autre!');
                res.render('admin/edit_page', {
                    title: title,
                    slog: slog,
                    content: content,
                    id: id
                });
            } else {
                Page.findById(id, function (err, page) {
                    console.log(id)
                    if (err)
                        console.log(err)

                    page.title = title;
                    page.slog = slog;
                    page.content = content;

                    page.save(function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err)
                        } else {
                            req.flash('success', 'page sauvegardée')
                            res.redirect('/admin/pages')
                        }
                    })

                })

            }

        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a minimal error with your string. There is an space at the end.

The string `5fa41e7f4ee57a30687e80e9`  should be `5fa41e7f4ee57a30687e80e9`

Using mongoose I have check this and works:

```js
var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5fa41e7f4ee57a30687e80e9");
```

Also I've explained how `ObjectId` works in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64755520/casterror-cast-to-objectid-failed-for-value-xxx-at-path-id-for-model-prod/64755665#64755665) If you want to check that.